# jQuery doesn't affect css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm trying to use jQuery to have text be conditionally invisible. The text in question is in html as follows:

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="bad-pass">Password is incorrect.</div>
    <div class="good-pass">Password is correct.</div>
</div>
```

The related css is as follows:

```
.info {
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
.info div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.info div:last-child {
    color: green;
}
```

Then, I call the following function, passing in either true or false(it doesn't matter which, neither work.)

```
function updatePass(correct) {
    if(correct) {
        $(".good-pass").css("visibility", "visible");
        $(".good-pass").css("line-height", "1");
        $(".bad-pass").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    else {
        $(".good-pass").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $(".bad-pass").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why the css properties aren't changing when I call the function to have jQuery change them?

EDIT:

I ended up giving up on the jQuery and getting the ideal result in PHP, as I'm already using PHP elsewhere in the document. HOWEVER, as Travis J. pointed out, the code worked in jsFiddle, which thoroughly confuses me. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery properly? Are you loading script on DOMReady? Any errors in `console`?

Comment: You are selecting the **ID** instead of **class**. Change `$("#bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");` to `$(".bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");`.

Comment: Other than that one typo (`#` instead of `.` in the last one) your code works correctly. [Here is some proof](http://jsfiddle.net/3AmgY/).

Comment: It's recommended not to change CSS directly in Javascript. The more maintainable approach is to modify the classes of the DOM element. So have css selectors like .hiddenElement and .visibleElement with visibility: hidden and visibility: visible respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both seem to work for me, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tTrcL/

One thing to note was that you were incorrectly targetting `$(".bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");` with `$("#bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");`

js

```
function updatePass(correct) {
if(correct) {
    $(".good-pass").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".good-pass").css("line-height", "1");
    $(".bad-pass").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
else {
    $(".good-pass").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(".bad-pass").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".bad-pass").css("line-height", "1");
}
}
updatePass(false);
setTimeout(function(){updatePass(true);},3000);
```

Comment: +1 With everybody being busy with `visibility`, you are the only one who pointed the typos. :)

Comment: I already fixed the typo. I was originally using IDs, but after some google searching found out that it may have been why it wasn't working, so I changed it. I must have just missed that particular one while making the change. Either way, the code doesn't work when I run it in context. The css is completely unchanged after the function is called. Could it be because of my browser? I'm using google chrome.

Comment: It is not your browser. Perhaps it is something else with your code. Perhaps try putting an alert inside of the function to make sure that when you call it, it actually runs. Did you check your console for errors? They can result in code not being executed. Perhaps this div is nested in an area which does have `display:none` defined? Are there conflicting css definitions? It is hard to know what the issue is aside from what was posted in the original question because there is no code or example to see. Perhaps if you can reproduce this in a jsfiddle that would help me or others to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure you realize what your asking for. There is an incredible amount of code this is nested within, and I can only show you some of it. I'll do my best, however using google chrome's convenient source showing and css rule modifying abilities, I know that jQuery is simply not updating the css properties. After the javascript function is called, the properties are the same as they were before the function was called, even though at least one of the properties should have changed.

Comment: @ColinMoore - Try to reproduce the issue in jsfiddle with as little code as possible. It is important to be able to give an example without divulging all of your code. You don't have to use the exact code you used, just some code that will exhibit the same issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Whatever the case, jsFiddle ran the code and it worked. I tested the functions from the console, and now they work. The only place they don't work is when php echos the call. Could it be because I'm calling the functions within a previously loaded script tag?

Comment: @ColinMoore - Does php echo the call before the dom is loaded?

Comment: I don't actually know. I just have it echo into script tags and the functions don't run. I would assume then that the answer is no?

Comment: @Colin - You may want to try to attach the function call to the dom ready method of jquery. `$(function(){ updatePass(false); });` when you echo. This will ensure that the function is called once the dom is loaded.

Comment: That didn't change anything, unfortunately. It definitely is echoing as you suggested in the source, however the functions still have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're loading your jQuery, and using a dom ready event like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

You can also merge the first two calls like this:

```
$('.good-pass').css({visibility:'visible',lineHeight:'1'});
```

Comment: `line-height: 1px` is very different from `line-height: 1`.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the difference and am intentionally NOT using line-height: 1px.

Answer (score 0):

You do a mistake on your css. Change from:

```
.info {
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
.info div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.info div:last-child {
    color: green;
}
```

to:

```
.info div{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.info div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.info div:last-child {
    color: green;
}
```

Your jquery code change the visibility of .bad-pass and .good-pass but the .info block is all time hidden.

Comment: From the [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-visibility): **hidden:**
The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. *Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have `'visibility: visible'`*.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
Create a class in your CSS and fix the one that is not correct

```
.info div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.info div:last-child {
    color: green;
}
.shown{
   visibility:visible;
   line-height: 1;
}
.notshow{
     visibility:hidden;
     line-height: 0;
}
```

now use those classes:

First add it during your document ready call:

```
$('.info div').addClass("notshown");
```

Then use your function to toggle em:

```
function updatePass(correct) {
    if(correct) {
        $(".good-pass").addClass"shown").removeClass("notshown");
        $(".bad-pass").addClass"notshown").removeClass("shown");
    }
    else {
        $(".bad-pass").addClass"shown").removeClass("notshown");
        $(".good-pass").addClass"notshown").removeClass("shown");
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
OR, simply hide and show em:
CSS:

```
.info div:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.info div:last-child {
    color: green;
}
```

code:

```
$('.info div').hide();

function updatePass(correct) {
    if(correct) {
        $(".good-pass").show();
        $(".bad-pass").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".good-pass").hide();
        $(".bad-pass").show();
    }
}
```

NOTE this would also work for simpler CSS (check the color - do want red on good? seems odd to me but that is what you have in yours)

```
.good-pass {
    color: red;
}
.bad-pass {
    color: green;
}
```